# Update TIME mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

`mySql :`
Your `SQL` query has been executed successfully

0 rows affected by the last statement inside the procedure

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `update_adm`(OUT `sp_out` INT(11), IN `sp_email` VARCHAR(50) CHARSET utf8)
NO SQL
BEGIN 
UPDATE `admin` SET `last_try`=curtime() WHERE `email`=sp_email;
SET sp_out=ROW_COUNT();
END
```

why 0 rows affected by the last statement inside the procedure ?!

edited :

When I replace `sp_email` with correct value like navid@yahoo.com in my stored procedure, it works perfectly !

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `update_adm`()
NO SQL
BEGIN 
UPDATE `admin` SET `last_try`=curtime() WHERE `email`='navid@yahoo.com';
END
```

Answer (score 0):

From the MySQL command line, the output is as expected.

```
mysql> delimiter $$
mysql> CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost PROCEDURE update_adm( ...
    -> END$$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.16 sec)

mysql> delimiter ;

mysql> insert into admin values (null,'foo');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> call update_adm(@cnt,'foo');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> call update_adm(@cnt,'bar');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

When I call the procedure with an email that exists, I get a message back showing 1 row was affected. When I call the procedure with an email that does exist, it returns a message back showing 0 rows affected.

I believe the message you are seeing is from the client interface.  What client are you using to call the procedure?

Comment: the table field 'last_try' did not changed, when i use above query in phpmyadmin->sql ,query work perfect, and 'last_try' update